# Tensorflow- AttributeError: 'KeepAspectRatioResizer' object has no attribute 'per_channel_pad_value'

Tags: python, tensorflow

So, I trained an object detection model and now I want to export .ckpt files.
When I try to export the .ckpt files:

```
python export_inference_graph.py --input_type image_tensor --pipeline_config_path training/faster_rcnn_inception_v2_pets.config --trained_checkpoint_prefix training3/model.ckpt-47816 --output_directory inference_graph
```

I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "export_inference_graph.py", line 147, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 126, in run
    _sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "export_inference_graph.py", line 143, in main
    FLAGS.output_directory, input_shape)
  File "/home/ubuntu/tensorflow1/models/research/object_detection/exporter.py", line 454, in export_inference_graph
    is_training=False)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/object_detection-0.1-py3.6.egg/object_detection/builders/model_builder.py", line 101, in build
    add_summaries)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/object_detection-0.1-py3.6.egg/object_detection/builders/model_builder.py", line 274, in _build_faster_rcnn_model
    image_resizer_fn = image_resizer_builder.build(frcnn_config.image_resizer)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/object_detection-0.1-py3.6.egg/object_detection/builders/image_resizer_builder.py", line 83, in build
    if keep_aspect_ratio_config.per_channel_pad_value:

AttributeError: 'KeepAspectRatioResizer' object has no attribute 'per_channel_pad_value'
```

It seems that everybody has this working fine and have no problems with this.
Could anyone please tell me what is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a few months later, but I just encountered this issue too!

It seems the image_resizer.proto is missing the per_channel_pad_value attribute.
Update the proto file to include the attribute, from here:
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/protos/image_resizer.proto 
recompile it and then try again.

Should work this time.